# Import export service for fully scaled environment

Tags: 2013-sp1, importexportservice

We have fully scaled CM environment with 6 CM servers. We are trying to implement utility to export specific schema from source to destination and perform the content synchronization at destination. For moving schema from source to destination, we are trying to use ImportExport service.

The problem that we are having is,

> when we perform export using ImportExport service the export package
>   is created on either of 6 CM servers so there is no way to identify
>   where package is created so we can't pass it to import. Same thing is happening for import as we are not aware of the server which will be connected for import and package may not even be available there to the server connected.

How can we resolve this issue? Is there any way we can specify the package location to be available to both source and destination servers.

Approaches that we have tried till now and outcome of the same:

> 1. Tried to connect to individual CM server on source and destination: Since, CME is running SSL as per client requirement and SSL certificate is for load balanced endpoint, can't connect to individual server as it gives SSL/TLS error.
> 2. Provided shared location on the server to export the package and use the same shared location for importing the package: With this
>      approach no way to find the location of export package i.e. on which of the 6 server it got created and also during import it is not able
>      to locate workingDirectory and import fails.
> 3. Generate the export package then manually copy it to all 6 destination servers for import and then run the import process and
>      then clean up destination location: This is not the preferred approach.

Comment: did you try content porter? it will download package to your local machine?

Comment: Load balancing is not correctly support by CP now.
I'd suggest you to try moving by second option (use shared folder).
What exception did you get on import? Did you change workingFolder configuration attribute? It seems you have changed only packagesLocation attribute in the export node.

Comment: Where can I change working folder attribute? I did not find it to be a property for import export service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no other approach available to handle the mentioned scenario.

We went ahead with approach 3 "Generate the export package then manually copy it to all 6 destination servers for import and then run the import process and then clean up destination location: This is not the preferred approach."

Answer (score -1):

Hiren.
I suggest you to chose second option and use shared folder for exporting/importing packages. Here example of my configuration for ImportExport in the TCM configuration. Probaly on your system workingFolder(in the ImportExport element) is missed or linked to non-shared folder.

```
<importExport maxProcessCount="1" workingFolder="C:\Program Files\Tridion\ImportExport\Temp" processLogLocation="C:\Program Files\Tridion\log" transactionTimeout="0" userReplyTimeout="3600">
<export threadCount="1" packagesLocation="C:\Program Files\Tridion\ImportExport\Packages" />
<undo undoPackagesLocation="C:\Program Files\Tridion\ImportExport\UndoPackages" />
```

Comment: The suggestion should have been fine if it was only impact ImportExport service, the modification that you are suggesting will impact content porter so which is not desired.

Comment: Content porter is a UI wrapper above ImportExport...Better to say - default implementation to simplify your life. If somebody wants he can implement own UI helper for exporting/importing content from Tridion. Furthermore you didn't mention anything about Content Porter in your initial question.
BTW...I don't see any critical impact for Content Porter. During Uploading package for importing it, it will put package exactly to configured "workingFolder"...Our configuration is default values, which can be changed on demand.

Comment: If content porter also uses the importexport service internally then I guess content porter can also have the problem that I have described above. Correct? (if you can edit your answer to include the details of comments that you have)